# Regular expression [\s]* in Linux

Tags: regex, linux, grep

Could you please tell me what is expected result of command listed below?

```
/usr/bin/authselect current | /usr/bin/grep 'Profile[\s]*ID:'
```

As far as I can understand expected results are:

```
ProfilesID: sssd
Profile\ID: sssd
```

so Nessus is wrong :)

Comment: `\s` is not a basic regular expression escape sequence.

Comment: @chabo, see how Barmar's edits make this question way more approachable?  Hopefully your next question, you can format it while you write it.   If you're not going to talk about Nessus at all, it's not really relevant and you can just omit that detail

Comment: In PCRE, you can put escape sequences inside `[]`. @DanielFarrell

Comment: Ah, I see your point - it's not a regular expression escape sequence so it's "just" a standard character match.